# How to configure keycloak-(nodejs-)connect to use PKCE?

Tags: node.js, express, pkce, keycloak-connect, keycloak-nodejs-connect

I have an express app that I want to secure with `keycloak-connect`. I have not found any documentation or examples of how to set up an Authorization Code Flow with PKCE in this middleware.

I think I have configured Keycloak (IDP) correctly, because authentication from the app fails due to the middleware not transmitting neither `code_challenge` nor `code_challenge_method` parameters, which the auth server rejects:

```
auth_callback
    1
error
    invalid_request
error_description
    Missing parameter: code_challenge_method
state
    b720bdf4-daf8-4aa7-8525-be02404396a6
```

Middleware configuration:

```js
{
    realm: 'SomeRealm',
    'auth-server-url': 'https://auth-server.url/auth/',
    'ssl-required': 'all',
    resource: 'Some-client-ID',
    'public-client': true,
    'confidential-port': 0,
}
```

Is `keycloak-connect` even capable of utilising this flow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[keycloak-connect](https://www.npmjs.com/package/keycloak-connect) does not support PKCE as of now.

See the discussion I found at https://keycloak.discourse.group/t/keycloak-connect-node-js-pkce/8285 There someone suggests to switch to another library, which supports PKCE (i.e. [node-openid-client](https://github.com/panva/node-openid-client))

Regarding the server configuration, I guess you followed https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/#advanced-settings and section about PKCE, so that should be working as expected.

Comment: I managed to get it to work by using the `express-openid-connect` library :)
Thanks for the info regarding keycloak-connect and PKCE